# docusign api - ACCOUNT LACKS PERMISSIONS exception when creating an enveloppe with display or signerMustAcknowledge

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to create an envelope with a main document and several other supplementary ones via the REST API (on the POST /envelopes point).

Works fine except that i'd like to display some docs as supplementary one (asking for a view or view and accept)

Problem is that I cannot set the display / signerMustAcknowledge document property, got an ACCOUNT LACKS PERMISSIONS exception letting me know specifically that these 2 property are forbidden. Does anybody ever had such an issue ?

```
{
  :status=>"sent",
  :eventNotification=>{
    :enveloppeEvents=>["Sent", "Delivered", "Completed", "Declined", "Voided"], 
    :url=>"http://requestb.in/16wh0yw1"},
  :emailSubject=>"Sale pack",
  :recipients=>
    {
     :signers=>[
      {
        :email=>"me@gmail.com",
        :name=>"Nicolas",
        :recipientId=>1,
        :clientUserId=>1447,
        :tabs=> {
          :signHereTabs=>[{..., :required=>true}],
          :dateSignedTabs=>[{..., :required=>true}],
          :textTabs=>[{..., :required=>true}]
       }
     }
   ]
 },
 :documents=>
   [{:name=>"doc 1",
    :documentId=>1,
    :fileExtention=>"pdf",
    :documentBase64=> '...'
    :includeInDownload => true,
    :display => 'modal',
    :signerMustAcknowledge => 'view'
   }]
 }

 => RestClient::BadRequest: {
   "errorCode": "ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSIONS",
   "message": "This Account lacks sufficient permissions. Account does not have permission to set 'display' or 'signermustacknowledge' properties on document facture.pdf (Purchase)."
    }
```

Thanks in advance !  Nicolas

EDiT : i'm using the legacy authentication with my integration account (within the request header ). Account is a demo one created a week ago, and request is post on /envelopes

Comment: You're using the brand new supplemental documents API features. It could be that default demo accounts didn't include this feature. I will investigate with the internal DocuSign folks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, Dec 22, 2016, the default permission set for new demo accounts does not include the Supplemental Documents feature.

Solution:

If you have a sales or technical contact at DocuSign, ask them to add the **Allow Supplemental Documents** permission to your demo account.

If you don't have such a contact, file a case with DocuSign support

I anticipate that the permission will be included with new demo accounts in the future, but we're not quite there yet.

Comment: Actually you need an entreprise account to enable this feature, according to docusign support

Comment: The enterprise account issue only applies when your integration goes into production. A different issue is that the free sandbox accounts hosted on demo.docusign.com don't currently include the feature. You can have it enabled for your demo account for free by asking customer support.