# resend envelope returns 'ENVELOPE_CANNOT_CORRECT_INVALID_STATE'

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to resend an email notification with API [/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients?resend_envelope=true],but it returns an error.

[Error Info]
ENVELOPE_CANNOT_CORRECT_INVALID_STATE.
This account may not have 'correct' permission, or the envelope state is not 'sent' or 'delivered

I'm sure the envelope's state is 'sent'. Is there any problem with permission?
I tried to search the 'correct' permission, but there is no such item on setting page.

I saw the similar problem like

[createCorrect view returns ENVELOPE_CANNOT_CORRECT_INVALID_STATE on 'sent' envelope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49885427/createcorrect-view-returns-envelope-cannot-correct-invalid-state-on-sent-envel)

[docusign api - ACCOUNT LACKS PERMISSIONS exception when creating an enveloppe with display or signerMustAcknowledge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41230708/docusign-api-account-lacks-permissions-exception-when-creating-an-enveloppe-wi)

The answers look like it can't solve by user.

Is there anyone know how to solve this problem. Is there is no solution unless to ask DocuSign support to add permission to my account?

Comment: What are you trying to do? what is the scenario and the actual goal here?

Answer (score 0):

If the envelope is indeed still in a 'sent' state and you're seeing this message, you likely do not have the ability to Correct envelopes enabled at the account level. If you do have the ability to Correct envelope enabled at the account level there's likely something else going on, either way we're going to need an envelopeId to dig in.

Go ahead and open a case on support.docusign.com, someone from my team can review the envelope / accountId to see which path we need to take to resolve this. The last time I ran into this situation it was the account-level toggle, once I'd enabled that for the customer they were able to get their workflows back up and running.

Regards,

Matt